# Android BroadcastReceiver behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I've got a normal java class (not an Activity) which implements an element of my app including a Notification with 2 actions: the first action fires a PendingIntent launching a brand-new activity while the other broadcasts an intent which will be caught in a Receiver class extending BroadcastReceiver and all goes well (for now is only playing a sound from RAW directory)
Since i need to update particular aspects of the object implemented in the first java class, I put the receiver in my class, extending BroadcastReceiver this way, but the test sound is not played at all. The code in the onReceive method is the same in both classes.

**SingleInstance.java**

```
package com.thepier.ingresstimer;

*various imports*
public class SingleInstance extends BroadcastReceiver {

/* Notification Misc */
private int ID;
private NotificationManager nm;

/* App context */
private Context cntx;

/* Contatore */
private int intCounter = 0;

/* Portal Data */
private int hackMax = 4; /* hackMax minimo */
private long coolTime = 300000; /* millisecondi = 5 minuti */
private long burnTime = 14400000; /* millisecondi = 4 ore */

/* Portal Cooldowns */
CountDownTimer cooldownTimer;
CountDownTimer burnoutTimer;

*other code*

public void showNotification () {

    Intent intentPref = new Intent(cntx, PreferencesActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(cntx, 0, intentPref, 0);

    Intent intentHack = new Intent(cntx, SingleInstance.class);
    //OR Intent intentHack = new Intent(cntx, HackReceiver.class);
    intentHack.putExtra("ID", this.ID);
    intentHack.putExtra("maxH", this.hackMax);
    intentHack.putExtra("curH", this.intCounter);
    PendingIntent pIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cntx, 0, intentHack, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(cntx)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Cooldown terminato")
            .setTicker("Cooldown terminato")
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_new, "Hack", pIntent2)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_settings, "Impostazioni", pIntent1)
            .setContentText("Hack: "+intCounter+"/"+hackMax);

    nm.notify(ID, mBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sfx_portal_hacking_alien);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
}
```

**HackReceiver.java**

```
package com.thepier.ingresstimer;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class HackReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public HackReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sfx_portal_hacking_alien);
            mediaPlayer.start();


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you register the first one like you did the second?

Comment: Works now, forgot the empty constructor needed by BroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: forgot the empty constructor needed by BroadcastReceiver